# Baltar & Felix's secret

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In BSG (2005), season 4, episode 13, Baltar calls Felix in the CIC, and mentions "our little secret, sealed with a special pen." Similarly, when Felix visits Baltar in his cell (I can't remember the episode number), Baltar whispers a secret in Felix's ear. Does anyone know what the secret(s) they're referring too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to watch this webisode [The Face of the Enemy](http://cliqueclack.com/tv/2009/01/31/if-you-want-to-know-gaetas-secret-watch-the-webisodes/) to learn what the secret is.
If you want the SPOILER read below

> Baltar was aware of Gaeta's secret relationship with a dishonest copy of 8 which lead to a lot of civilian deaths.
>  he whispered: "I know what your Eight did"

Comment: I agree this is the most likely answer. However, it's disappointing because it makes this secret unexplained in the series proper. Another possibility is that Felix lied under oath about Baltar signing the execution order "of his own free will", this could be "their little secret, signed with a special pen". (Though I agree, the webisodes are the most likely answer).

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't even know about the webisodes!

Comment: Also in support of this answer, it explains Felix Gaeta's unrelenting and uncompromising hatred of Cylons in later episodes, and his opposition to any sort of alliance.

Answer (score 4):

The Battlestar Galactica "Face of the Enemy" webisodes (which are pretty much impossible to find anywhere these days - and if I'm wrong on this, I'd love to know where to get them - ETA: I'm dumb. They're all on Hulu.com as it turns out) are definitely meant to be the answer to this question. In the commentary to the webisodes, writer Jane Espenson said that they wanted to resolve this unanswered question from the Season 3 episode "Taking a Break From All Your Worries" (the one you refer to where Baltar whispers a secret to Gaeta and Gaeta stabs him), about what Baltar said to Felix. However, the webisodes are not the originally-intended answer to your question.

Originally, according to DVD commentary by the show's creator Ronald Moore, Baltar and Gaeta's secret was meant to be part of a larger storyline in Season 3 that was cut. In Moore's commentary, he explains that a story was going to come out during Baltar's trial of pre-Cylon Occupation atrocities that happened on New Caprica involving Saggitarons being massacred (Saggitarons, as may or may not know, are sometimes referred to as a racial group in the BSG 'verse that are frequently marginalized and discriminated against for their religious-based beliefs in pacifism and the avoidance of using modern medicine).

The backstory that was supposed to come out during Baltar's trial is not well explained by Moore, but he mentions that the atrocities were somehow going to involve Zarek being culpable and possibly Baltar too, or at least Baltar was going to have not done anything about it at the time. The secret that Baltar was intended to be whispering in Gaeta's ear in that episode was that he was going to falsely pin responsibility for the Saggitaron murders onto Gaeta, who had had nothing to do with it. However, Moore eventually determined that the Saggitaron storyline was so terrible, that they should cut it out, even though some of the episodes featuring it had already been filmed. So they cut out all references to this storyline that they could in whatever had already been filmed, but they could not manage to cut out this bit with Baltar and Gaeta's secret without compromising the integrity of this particular episode, so they had to leave it in.

(My pet theory is that this is also one of the reasons why around this time, we have these random scenes of Zarek repeatedly urging Roslin against public trials for Baltar and any other people accused of having committed atrocities on New Caprica, and even recommending that Roslin declare martial law, which is somewhat out of character for him. I think the idea was supposed to be that he didn't want this info to come out in public trials. But I have no proof for this.)

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: This is a well written exposition on Gaeta’s psychological motivations of his mutiny. I’d like to add that Dualla’s
suicide was also the last straw that broke the camel’s
back. Her death seemed to affect him a lot since they work together closely in CIC throughout the series and before the Cylon’s attack. It could almost be hinted that Gaeta might hv had affection towards her.

Comment: Good point. I agree that Dualla could be taken as a factor too. We're shown a beat of Adama going into the morgue to see Dualla's body and passing by Gaeta, who is just outside the morgue, looking traumatized. He was the last person to see her alive, and witnessed her death. 

In previous seasons, they had some key emotional scenes together around times of personal stress. During the episode Unfinished Business, we see them hanging out socially in New Caprica, both in the present and in the flashbacks. I think Dee would have had better luck  than anyone talking Felix down from mutiny.